# Is it possible to add using with CodeFluent Entities snippet?

Tags: code-generation, code-snippets, using-directives, codefluent

I would like to create a CodeFluent Entities snippet with some linq query inside:

```
return BaseList.Where(cd => cd.StartDate <= DateTime.UtcNow && cd.EndDate > DateTime.UtcNow)
    .OrderByDescending(cd => cd.Rate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

After building the model I have a compilation error because I'm lacking some using:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
```

in the generated file.

Is there a way to add them ?

Comment: Are you using the graphical modeler or raw XML files? CLR4 or CLR2?

Comment: We are using the graphical modeler and CLR4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Business Object Model (BOM) Producer allows to define additional imports.

- Open the BOM configuration
- Go to advanced Tab
- Set `Namespace Imports` property to, for example, `System.Linq, MyCustomNamespace`

The producer will output these usings.

```
Imports MyCustomNamespace
Imports System.Linq

using System.Linq;
using MyCustomNamespace;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add namespace imports in generated code using the BOM producer properties:

- double click on the producer node in Visual Studio's Solution Explorer
- select the "Advanced" property grid tab
- Add "System" and "System.Linq" as namespace imports (separated by a comma)

[image: CodeFluent Entities BOM Producer Advanced Properties]

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the *System* namespace, I've found the solution quite easily: just add the namespace before the type name.

```
return BaseList.Where(cd => cd.StartDate <= System.DateTime.UtcNow && cd.EndDate > System.DateTime.UtcNow)
    .OrderByDescending(cd => cd.Rate)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

What about the extensions method ?